# How to clean superfluous merges from the git history?

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I've a co-worker that attempted to debug Azure DevOps pipelines by editing and committing e.g. `azure-pipelines-1.yml` and `requirements.txt` to the `master` branch, resulting in series of commits and associated merges. See a snippet of the resulting git history as the end of this question.

What strategy would be feasible for cleaning up the resulting git history and eliminate all the `azure-pipelines-1.yml` and `requirements.txt` commits to make it look somewhat like this:

```
* | f1827ab Disabled root logger
* | 4941773 SNOW API and AD validator
* | 6ba3ce7 Handler unit tests
* | 76af104 slate3k for handling PDF and openpyxl for handling Excel
* | 6002e95 Jira "diff" scan, Jira project scan, Stash project scan
* | 11d4a2a Explicit column names for ORM models
* | a5524e1 Updated Dockerfile, pip.conf, and requirements.txt
* | f536cef Refactored packages for unittest. Created unit tests for handlers
```

?

In particular, I cannot use `git rebase -i`, because it cannot handle merges?

**`git log`**:

```
*   9e4028d (HEAD -> master, appsec/master) Merge branch 'master' of https://azuredevops.danskenet.net/Main/Application%20Security/_git/sds
|\
| * 5b4b06d Updated requirements.txt
| * e6be15d Added file Pipfile
| * 7cbae95 Updated requirements.txt
| * 6416de8 Updated azure-pipelines-1.yml
| * 4bea01c Updated azure-pipelines-1.yml
| * 995410c Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * 2c708e1 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * 3c2fa59 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * f712143 Updated requirements.txt
| * 529b0cc Updated requirements.txt
| * d84d97c Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * d2e8ca7 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * b2ddfb1 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * 4793fd0 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * de8cb72 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * 6571ef6 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * a5cde18 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * fe93475 Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * f4d6413 Updated requirements.txt
| * dcdd00f Updated requirements.txt
| * b69410f Updated blackduck.yml
| * 876a93b Updated requirements.txt
| * b6a5016 Updated blackduck.yml
| * 8a3fdd7 Updated requirements.txt
* | f1827ab Disabled root logger
* | 4941773 SNOW API and AD validator
* | 6ba3ce7 Handler unit tests
* | 76af104 slate3k for handling PDF and openpyxl for handling Excel
* | 6002e95 Jira "diff" scan, Jira project scan, Stash project scan
* | 11d4a2a  Explicit column names for ORM models
* | a5524e1 Updated Dockerfile, pip.conf, and requirements.txt
* | f536cef Refactored packages for unittest. Created unit tests for handlers
|/
*   536d2c2 Merge remote-tracking branch 'appsec/master' into master
|\
| * 465a25e Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * 8ac226b Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
| * c22a1be Update azure-pipelines-1.yml for Azure Pipelines
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get 100% of your needs, but I think you *are* looking for `git rebase -i` : you probably want to replay all commits of the "side branch" on top of :

```
* f1827ab Disabled root logger
```

Here is one way to do that :

```
# from master :
git checkout -b wip 5b4b06d
git rebase -i f1827ab
```

The interactive rebase will give you an opportunity to drop all the commits you want to exclude ; you may also group together (`squash` or `fixup`) several commits into one.

After you have finished your work on this temporary `wip` branch, you can set `master` to that specific commit :

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard wip
```

---

*general warning about `git reset --hard`* :

`git reset --hard` is one of those few destructive git commands, which can erase non committed modifications from your disk, without any way to recover tem.

Use it only if your worktree is clean, or if you know for a fact that you can throw away all the changes on disk.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you use `HEAD^2` and why is that not ambiguous, since `HEAD` has two parents? If I in the mean time had committed on top of `HEAD`, your approach here would not be possible, would it?

Comment: granted :) replacing `HEAD^2` with the explicit hash in your history : `5b4b06d`

Comment: Note : my current answer would delete additional commits on top of master. If you have additional *non merge* commits on top of master : simply run `git rebase -i 5b4b06d` from your current `master` branch.

Comment: If you have additional *merge* commits on top of master : run `git rebase -m -i 5b4b06d` ; the sequencer script will be a bit more involved, but still allow you to rewrite what you want (drop useless commits, possibly squash several other commits together).

Comment: I see. So it's possible to rebase a branch with merge commits? I thought that branches needed to be linear in order to rebase them? The help on `git rebase --merge` doesn't provide much information, i.e.: *Use merging strategies to rebase.*

Comment: @Shuzheng : see the ["Rebasing Merges"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges) section. You will have additional commands for the sequencer : label, reset and merge.